# copy an one eigen matrix of vectors

Tags: eigen

I have

`A`(matrix of vectors with length = `depth`) is 5x5 (5 rows and 5 cols).

`depth` = 3 (it is the length of vector of any cell of matrix A).

`B`(matrix of single values) is 75 x Any (5*5*3 rows and Any cols).

`x_size_kernel` = 5.

`block_idx` is the index, here for example we have made it equal 0 (for one column of matrix B only)

The task of this simple and strict example is to copy all vectors of matrix `A` to one (first column) of matrix `B`.

Now I solve the problem like this (it is concrete example with precise data)

```
Eigen::MatrixXf B;
B = Eigen::MatrixXf(x_size_kernel * y_size_kernel * depth, 100).setZero();

Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::VectorXf, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> A;
A.resize(5, 5);
auto depth = 3;
for (auto yy = 0; yy < A.rows(); yy++) {
    for (auto xx = 0; xx < A.cols(); xx++) {
        A(yy, xx).resize(depth);
    }
}

auto block_idx = 0;

// and here are all copy for one column of matrix B
for (auto my = 0; my < x_size_kernel; my++) {
    for (auto mx = 0; mx < x_size_kernel; mx++) {
        // add the next column of block data
        B.col(block_idx).
        segment(mx * depth + my * x_size_kernel * depth, depth).noalias() =
        A(my, mx);
    }
}
```

But the above code is very slow, so I need more fast code. Maybe somebody know how to copy data in such way using only `Eigen` one pass.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Are the sizes known at compile-time? Are 5x5 and 3 the actual sizes or are these just for illustration?

Comment: Hello, see revised post above please